# Let $a_n>0$ for $n \geq 1$ and let series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverge. Let $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n > 1$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Prove that the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{S_n \ln S_n}$$ diverges and the series : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{S_n \ln^2 S_n}$$ converges. (Using the famous criteria I pressume). For some reason I cannot see which criteria to use here that would be effective. On first glance Dalambere's criteria seems applicable but am not sure at all how to use it.

Comment: This is likely to get downvoted unless you tell us what you've thought about on 1. You should also eliminate 2 here, as it's a completely different problem.

Comment: I have edited, with that respect.

Comment: It looks like there are important hypotheses in the title. You should probably put those in the post, since a) it becomes more readable, and b) titles don't render on the SE app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First 
$$
\int_{S_{n}}^{S_{n+1}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln(x)}\leqslant\int_{S_{n}}^{S_{n+1}}\dfrac{dx}{S_{n}\ln(S_{n})}=\dfrac{1}{S_{n}\ln(S_{n})}\int_{S_{n}}^{S_{n+1}}dx=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{S_{n}\ln(S_{n})}
$$
for $S_{n+1}\geqslant S_n$ and $\dfrac1{x\ln(x)}\downarrow$. So 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{S_{n}\ln(S_{n})}\geqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\int_{S_{n}}^{S_{n+1}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=\int_{S_{1}}^{S_{N+1}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln(x)}=\ln(\ln(S_{N+1}))-\ln(\ln(S_{1}))\to\infty 
$$
for $S_N\to\infty$. So $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{S_{n}\ln(S_{n})}$ diverges.

Second
$$
\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_{n}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln^2(x)}\geqslant\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_{n}}\dfrac{dx}{S_{n}\ln^2(S_{n})}=\dfrac{1}{S_{n}\ln^2(S_{n})}\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_{n}}dx=\dfrac{a_{n}}{S_{n}\ln^2(S_{n})}
$$
for $S_{n}\geqslant S_{n-1}$ and $\dfrac1{x\ln^2(x)}\downarrow$. So 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{a_{n}}{S_{n}\ln^2(S_{n})}\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_{n}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln^2(x)}=\int_{S_{1}}^{S_{N}}\dfrac{dx}{x\ln^2(x)}=\dfrac{1}{\ln(S_{1})}-\dfrac{1}{\ln(S_{N+1})}\to\dfrac{1}{\ln(S_{1})} 
$$
for $S_N\to\infty$. So $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{S_{n}\ln^2(S_{n})}$ converges.

Comment: this first inequality is unclear

Comment: I just dont understand how it is so? How do you compare $x$ and $S_n$?

Comment: $S_{n+1}\geq S_n$ and $x\ln(x)\uparrow$, also $S_n>1, x\ln(x)>0$, so $\forall x\in [S_n,S_{n+1}], x\ln(x)>S_n\ln(S_n)$ (Sorry I made a mistake and I modify the proof).